# HashMap put method clarification

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a curious situation - there is a HashMap, that is initialized as follows:

```
    HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> downloadMap = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
```

and then I have the following things, that will be executed indefinitely via a quartz scheduler:

```
    myHashSet = retrieve(animal);
    downloadMap.put(myKey, myHashSet);
    // do stuff
    downloadMap.get(myKey).clear();
```

What happens after, is that one value gets associated with the different keys. So, for instance, I will have things like:

```
 Kitens [cute kitten, sad kitten]
 Puppies [cute kitten, sad kitten]
```

Which never should happen.

Particularly, after I retrieve the HashSet of the kittens:

```
 myHashSet = retrieve(animal);
```

myHashSet = [cute kitten, sad kitten]
downloadMap = Kittens [], Puppies[]

then put() is executed and I get:

```
 downloadMap =  Kitens [cute kitten, sad kitten], Puppies [cute kitten, sad kitten]
```

Does anyone knows why this is the case?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does your `retrieve(animal)` return? Where and how do you set `animal` and where is `myKey` changed?

Comment: retrieve(animal) returns HashSet<String>, based on the parameter animal - could be cat, puppy etc. If it is a cat, the hashset contains values such as [cute kitten, sad kitten], if its a puppy then then [cute puppy, sad puppy] etc. The animal is getting passed via quartz trigger to the job. There are no problem with retriever(animal) though - it returns what it supposed to return. EDIT: I've looked at the other responses and it seems that what it might be the problem with the retrieve(animal), particularly returning a new hashset each time it is called. I'll give it another tomorrow,thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you use the same `HashSet<String>` reference in all your values of the `HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>`. Knowing this, the problem is how you insert the `HashSet<String>`s in your `HashMap`. Note that you must use a new `HashSet<String>` reference for every key-value pair.

Update your question accordingly to receive a more specific answer.

Not directly associated to the real problem, it is better to program oriented to interfaces instead of direct class implementations. With this, I mean that you should declare the `downloadMap` variable as

```
Map<String, Set<String>> downloadMap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
```

Similar for the `Set`s that will be put in this map.

More info:

- [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to re-program `retrieve()` so it returns a different HashSet every time it is called.  In fact, my preferred solution consists in allowing the caller to specify where to `retrieve` objects as a parameter:

```
    myHashSet= retrieve( new HashSet<String>() ) ;
```

So, if a different program ever wanted to accumulate objects in a single set, it could simply do so by calling `retrieve` with the same set.  The client has the last word!